# Find and add 1 to the highest number in column 2 based on the input in column 1

Tags: excel

Using data similar to what's below, I want to fill in B7 with the next highest number that would be in associated with "Del"... the result should be "4".   And then continue that in each subsequent row, the number that is returned in the associated cell in column B will be 1 higher than the highest number already associated with that string in A.

```
   A     B
1  Del   1

2  Del   2

3  Pho   1

4  Del   3

5  ACF   1

6  Pho   2

7  Del   ____
```

Answer (score 1):

In Column B, you can use `=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)`

To explain the formula, we want to count from the first row to the current row any values that equal the current row's value.